# SUSE LINUX 11 - Being Able To Collect User Information (Audit)

Tags: linux, users, syslog, suse, audit

I added the following lines to the /etc/audit/audit.rules file and restarted the machine:

```
-w /etc/group -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/passwd -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/gshadow -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/shadow -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/security/opasswd -p wa -k identity
```

Creating a user from the CLI using the useradd command records the following audit message:

```
Sep 28 15:44:09 HK-CentOS-7 useradd[4065] : new user: name= test1, UID= 38263, GID= 38263, home= / home/test1, shell= / bin/ bash
```

Creating a user from the GUI does not output the same user information like the above and it only mentions that the /etc/passwd file was written to. Are there any additional settings that I need to configure to enable more information to be generated from the GUI user creation? I would like to know exactly what user was created.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters but what desktop manager are you using?

Comment: @MarkScheck I am using gdm.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies here. Yast2 will be able to filter the journald logs [17.6 Using YaST to Filter the systemd Journal](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP1/html/SLES-all/cha-journalctl.html#sec-journalctl-yast)